# xPath get value from tag style

Tags: html, xpath

HTML code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-image: url(https://www.example.org/image.jpg)};
</style>
```

Can I get a link to an image using xPath anyway? © google-tranlate
Help please, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get your URL via next XPath:

`translate(substring-after(//style/text(),"url"),')(};','    ')`

In this:

You get text from tag "STYLE": `//style/text()`

Then you get substring start from url `substring-after(//style/text(),"url")`

And in finally tou formatting this is substring, change special symbols on space, like `)(};` **:** `translate('your_substing','have_your_special_symbols','and_change_its_on_free_space')`